# Filtering an array of arrays JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function, that accepts an array of arrays as argument and filtering this array under certain condition. I will explain this condition later.
For example I have such array:

```
 const arr = [
  [1, 1, 20],
  [2, 1, 15],
  [3, 1.5, 15],
  [4, 1, 15],
  [5, 1, 20],
  [6, 1.5, 15],
  [7, 1, 25],
  [8, 1, 15],
  [9, 0, 15],
  [10, 0, 15],
  [11, 0, 15],
]
```

and the condition. I want to filter it by the value of the third column, but only if it's at least three in a sequence. The function should accept two arguments (or more if needed): value and array
So for example

```
 const filterByValue = (array, val) => { //definition 
     return filtredArr
   }
```

const newArr = filterByValue(array,15)
and now newArr should equal:

```
 [
   [2, 1, 15],
   [3, 1.5, 15],
   [4, 1, 15],
   [8, 1, 15],
   [9, 0, 15],
   [10, 0, 15],
   [11, 0, 15],
 ]
```

For now I only made:

```
const filterByValue = (arr, value) => {
      const newArr = arr.filter((elem, index) => elem[2] === value)
      return newArr
  }
```

but this function returns

```
  [
     [2, 1, 15],
     [3, 1.5, 15],
     [4, 1, 15],
     [6, 1.5, 15],
     [8, 1, 15],
     [9, 0, 15],
     [10, 0, 15],
     [11, 0, 15],
  ]
```

there shouldn't be [6,1.5,15]. I have no idea how it could be done to return only fragments of an array that contain at least three internal arrays in a row. Maybe any of you have any idea?

## edit more explanation

This sequence means to me that I want only output which internal arrays that contain a set value in the third value (value argument in a function), but that they also have internal arrays that follow each other (at least three). Let's assume that the function accepts arr (first array in my post) and value = 15. The first internal array contains 20 as the third value, so it falls off. The second is okey, the third also and the fourth also - and should return in this situation 2,3,4 internal board (because they follow three in succession). Then the fifth value is 20, the sixth value is 15, but the next (seventh) value 25 again, so the function should not take into account the sixth table (because it is not followed by at least two tables that have the value 15). In the table 8,9,10,11 we have the value 15, and these are four tables (i.e. at least three). Therefore, the function should return an array containing the following tables 2,3,4 and 8,9,10,11. The sixth array contains the value 15, but not followed by two more that would have this value as well. The expected output is the second board in my post.

Comment: I read your question but I haven't realised what is the criteria based on which you are filtering the array? Can you add a better description of the filtering criteria and also an expected output?

Comment: what does 3 in a sequence mean, can you describe the criteria more?

Comment: Does  2, 4, 6 and 3, 6, 9 make a valid sequence for your use case or the common difference has to be 1? e.g. 1,2,3(valid) 1,3,4(invalid) 2,3,4(valid), 3,6,9(invalid)

Comment: I edited post for more explanation, thanks for your interest, a colleague below solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const filterByValue = (arr,value) => {
    let newArray = [];
    let cache = [];
    arr.forEach(elem => {
        if (elem[2] === value) {
            cache.push(elem);
        } else {
            if (cache.length >= 3) {
                newArray = newArray.concat(cache);
            }
            cache = [];
        }
    });
    if (cache.length >= 3) {
        newArray = newArray.concat(cache);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: This one works perfect. And its very elegant, I thought too complicated. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You could take a closure over an index and check if the values are in a sequence of three.

```js
const
    array = [[1, 1, 20], [2, 1, 15], [3, 1.5, 15], [4, 1, 15], [5, 1, 20], [6, 1.5, 15], [7, 1, 25], [8, 1, 15], [9, 0, 15], [10, 0, 15], [11, 0, 15]],
    value = 15,
    result = array.filter(
        (index => ({ 2: v }, i, a) => {
            if (v !== value) return false;
            if (index === i || a[i + 1][2] === value && a[i + 2][2] === value) {
                index = i + 1;
                return true;
            }
        })
        (-1)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you explain `{ 2: v }`, because it's an array in each iteration, how does it work?

Comment: in javascript, arrays are objects and this part takes a destructuring with property `2` from the array. basically it take the value from index `2`.

Comment: yeah I know that arrays are objects in js, but I didn't know that it could be parsed like that, I know that destructuring of arrays is using with square brackets,
can you provide any ref about that?

Comment: just the standard one: [Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `filter` and conditions based on whether match the value or not.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 1, 20],
  [2, 1, 15],
  [3, 1.5, 15],
  [4, 1, 15],
  [5, 1, 20],
  [6, 1.5, 15],
  [7, 1, 25],
  [8, 1, 15],
  [9, 0, 15],
  [10, 0, 15],
  [11, 0, 15],
];

const filterByValue = (array, val) =>
  array.filter((ar, i, items) => {
    if (ar[2] !== val) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return items[i - 1][2] === val || items[i + 1][2] === val;
    }
  });

console.log(filterByValue(arr, 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the cache array.

Check if element contains number 15 if yes increment the counter if that counter reaches at least 3 it means you can store those 3 element into a new list. Use the the difference between the current index and the counter to get from the first sequence element to the last one. Repeat the process until end of the array is reached.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 1, 20],
  [2, 1, 15],
  [3, 1.5, 15],
  [4, 1, 15],
  [5, 1, 20],
  [6, 1.5, 15],
  [7, 1, 25],
  [8, 1, 15],
  [9, 0, 15],
  [10, 0, 15],
  [11, 0, 15]
];

let cnt = 0;
let list = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // check if elements meet criteria
  while (i < arr.length && arr[i][arr[i].length - 1] === 15) {
    ++i;
    ++cnt;
  }
  // acumulate into your array if at least 3 elm
  if (cnt >= 3) {
    for (let j = i - cnt; j < i; j++) {
      list.push(arr[j]);
    }
  }
  cnt = 0;
}
console.log(list)
```